# How do I create a template in c++ that will only accept the list of types I provide?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I wanted to create operator for debugging purposes that would neatly output contents of some structures I may use in the program. The example of such an operator could be:

```
template<class T> ostream & operator << (ostream & os, vector<T> & vec) {
  for(auto & el : vec)
    os << vec << ' ';
  return os;
}
```

The thing is I wanted this operator also to write the contest of `std::set` in a similar fashion, but I do not see a way to make it a bit more specific without making it too general.

Is there some way to tell the template to accept type of T only when it is in a list of types I specify (for example `{vector<T>, set<T>, unordered_set<T>, multiset<T>}`)?

Comment: you can overload `operator<<` for only those types you want to overload it

Comment: I dont understand if you want to limit the set of types, or if you want more types. Title is the first, but your code suggests the latter. You want to use the same template for `vector<T>` and `set<T>` and any container with elements of type `T`?

Comment: Yes, but I though that maybe there is some shorter way of doing it and it is worth to ask.

Comment: I want for this operator to be used when trying to do ```cout << set_variable;``` but in the same time not to be used when outputting something like string.

Comment: please clarify what types the template should accept, the code you posted does only accept `vector<T>` not `std::string`

Comment: This should work like 4 copies of this code where each copy would have either ```vector<T>``` like above, or ```set<T>``` or ```multiset<T>```. I am not restricting what is inside of those containers, but only which types of containers I want to be seen by this operator. I simply think that copying this code 4 times seems not a practical thing to do.

Comment: the simpler solution is a `print(Iterator begin, Iterator end)` templated on the iterator type. It is still not clear if you want to restrict the types the template accepts (thats what the dupe is about)

Comment: Ok, now that I look at it, it seems to me that I do not want to restrict the types the template accepts, but rather the second parameter of overloaded operator.

Comment: title says "only accept the list of types I provide?" but the question is about a template that only accepts `std::vector<T>` and asks how to accept more, like `set<T>` and `multiset<T>`, thats 2 different question

Comment: My bad. Sorry for misleading.